# Certificate Expiration notification

Tags: apex, certification, certificates

I'm getting a self-assigned certificate expiration notification and unfortunately.

what are the top 5 reasons people create a self-assigned certificate for an application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To put in simple terms Self Signed Certificates are like false drivers licence .It provides security to a certain level but can be easily hacked but its still better than having nothing .Check this excellent [article](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-when-are-self-signed-certificates-acceptable.html)

Now why the certificates expired message exists is a mystery and there is a good blog with some [research](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-when-are-self-signed-certificates-acceptable.html) but its still a mystery but no harmful effects observed due to false positive.

Answer (score 4):

Our implementation consultant created one for us when we went live. We spent about five days trying to figure out why, and never found anything. We let it expire. Nothing bad happened. :)

Comment: It is basically used for testing purpose As it is not secure and third callout majorly use CA signed